# Created window using stdscr with curses library showing unwanted smiley characters in border instead of lines

Tags: c++, terminal, ncurses, curses

[Image with borders having unwanted chars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7A0G.gif) I am using curses library. Created window using stdscr API, it was working fine in previous versions with correct border lines. However, in new version I am getting smileys and unwanted characters in the border lines.

Help me in proceeding further.

Answer (score 0):

Without a (short) sample program and probably the command-line, one can only guess.  However, referring to "previous versions" sounds like a problem updating from ncurses5 to ncurses6 (about two years ago).  ncurses6 headers differ from ncurses5, changing the size of some datatypes.  If your command-line accidentally mixes ncurses5/ncurses6 headers versus libraries, you will get odd behavior for anything that uses video-attributes (colors, line-drawing, etc.).

Further information: [ncurses6 announcement](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce.html), August 2015.